# Bootstrap modal pop up with partial view works for one but gets block for another due to ajax GET request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have two links "Details" and "History", each one opens a modal pop, gets the html (partial view) from the server and display as content of the modal pop up. This works for Details but does not for History. They both have the same logic.

This is the Details link

```
<a class="modal-pop-up-action-link" title="Details" href="/MyController/Detail/10004" data-modal-url="/MyController/Detail/10004?partial=True" data-modal-title="Details">
<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
</a>
```

This is the History link

```
<a class="modal-pop-up-action-link" title="History" href="/MyController/History/10004" data-modal-url="/MyController/History/10004?partial=True" data-modal-title="Audit Histories">
<i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
</a>
```

Part of MyController actions

```
public async Task<ActionResult> History(int id, bool partial = false)
{

    // Logic to get the model    
    if (partial)
        return PartialView("_HistoryGridPartial", model);
    else 
        return View(model);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Detail(int id, bool partial = false)
{

    // Logic to get the model    
    if (partial)
        return PartialView("_DetailGridPartial", model);
    else 
        return View(model);
}
```

This is the History Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Histories";
}

<table class="table datatable table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Field 1 Title</th>
             <th>Field 2 Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (MyModel rd in Model)
        {
            <tr> 
             <td>@rd.Field1</td>
             <td>@rd.Field2</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Details Partial View

```
@model MyDetail
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">&nbsp;</span>
        <label>Details</label>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Field1):&nbsp;@Model.Field1
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and, finally the javascript call

```
$('.modal-pop-up-action-link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_WIDE,
        cssClass: 'bootstrap-dialog-model-pop-up',  
        title: '<h4>' + $(this).data("modal-title") + '</h4>',
        message: $('<div></div>').load($(this).data("modal-url")),
        buttons: [
            {
                label: 'Close',
                action: function(dialogItself) {
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

I understand that GET method should not be allowed in Ajax request to prevent Json hijacking. But, my question is, why it works in one but not in the other, any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,

Using Ajax GET to request a partial view is totally valid. What happened was the return result had error, the partial view is expecting an IEnumerable, but I passed MyViewModel, which contains the IEnumerable.  Now, changing the controller to return IEnumerable instead of MyViewModel worked.

Regarding to the GET response getting blocked, since there was an error in the request, the server was returning a json object (this is a global error handling we set up), it gets blocked because we don't allow json response in GET due to security purpose.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> History(int id, bool partial = false)
{

    // Logic to get the model    
    if (partial)
        return PartialView("_HistoryGridPartial", model.MyEnumerableList);
    else 
        return View(model);
}
```